# How is the texture getting destroyed in the following case?

Tags: c++, textures, sprite, sfml

In the SFML tutorials, it is said that the texture gets destroyed when you do something like this :-

```
sf::Sprite loadSprite(std::string filename) 
{ 
    sf::Texture texture; 
    texture.loadFromFile(filename); 

    return sf::Sprite(texture); 
} // error: the texture is destroyed here
```

How is the texture destroyed there when it returned correctly  ?

Comment: You need to learn about constructors, destructors, what they do, and when they run. In this case, the destructor for `texture` executes when the variable goes out of scope, no matter how that happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object `texture` is destroyed when its scope ends -- here at the end of the function. This is always the case for stack allocated variables, in contrast to data on the heap (that you create with `new` for example).

When you create a sprite, if you look closely at [its constructor signature](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.2/classsf_1_1Sprite.php#a2a9fca374d7abf084bb1c143a879ff4a), you actually never copy the texture but just give a ***reference*** to it. This means that as soon as the texture object is destroyed then you get a white sprite [as explained in the tutorial](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.2/graphics-sprite.php#the-white-square-problem).

Answer (score 1):

[Hiura](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30137165/1218980) is right and just to add to his great answer, I want to provide one way to overcome this situation.

You could make the `sf::Texture` a member variable of a class that is going to stay alive for the time you need it (the game, the scene, etc) and just pass around `sf::Sprite` objects.

Then, the code could look something like this:

```
sf::Sprite loadSprite(std::string filename) 
{ 

    this->mTexture.loadFromFile(filename); 

    // then only make copy of the sprite object
    return sf::Sprite(texture); 
}
```

If you need multiple texture (which will probably be the case), you should have a class that manages each `sf::Texture` object and that only returns a reference or a pointer to it or a new sprite and which loads Texture only if they're not already in memory.

I made a gist with of an old template that I used, it's the [TResourceManager](https://gist.github.com/emileber/8516592). It works with every type you want, you just need to make a Resource subclass but I won't get into the details here.

Comment: `this` is a pointer, use it as such. Or don't mention it, it's the same here. ;-)

Comment: It's to emphasize the use of a member variable, I'm just not doing much C++ lately and forgot temporarily about it being a pointer.